# How can I configure Drupal 6 to work with gmail?

Tags: drupal, gmail-imap

How can I configure Drupal 6 to work with gmail IMAP?

These are the errors I get when trying to send email from Drupal.

- warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 23sm231165iwn.2 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\acquia-drupal\includes\mail.inc on line 193.
- Unable to send e-mail. Please contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

These are the settings in my PHP.ini file.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = info@mysite.com
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this the SMTP module or something you've stirred up? If it's the SMTP module, use SSL, port 465. TLS gives problems (at least in my case).

Comment: This is in the PHP.ini file with the default installation of Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to *send* email, the [SMTP Authentication Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module is the way to go. I use the 6.x-1.x-dev version on a number of sites with no problem.

Comment: I needed to download the SMTP Authentication Support module. I assumed I could just configure Drupal to work as it was out of the box. Thank you, Keith.